# to find count of distinct values across two columns in r

Tags: r

I have two columns . both are of character data type. 
One column has strings and other has got strings with quote. 
I want to compare both columns and find the no. of distinct names across the data frame.

```
string f.string.name
john      NA
bravo     NA
NA        "john"
NA        "hulk"
```

Here the count should be 2, as john is common.

Somehow i am not able to remove quotes from second column. Not sure why.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The main problem I'm seeing are the `NA` values.
First, let's get rid of the quotes you mention.

```
dat$f.string.name <- gsub('["]', '', dat$f.string.name)
```

Now, count the number of distinct values.

```
i1 <- complete.cases(dat$string)
i2 <- complete.cases(dat$f.string.name)
sum(dat$string[i1] %in% dat$f.string.name[i2]) + sum(dat$f.string.name[i2] %in% dat$string[i1])
```

**DATA**

```
dat <-
structure(list(string = c("john", "bravo", NA, NA), f.string.name = c(NA, 
NA, "\"john\"", "\"hulk\"")), .Names = c("string", "f.string.name"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
table(str_replace_all(unlist(df), '["]', ''))

# bravo  hulk  john 
# 1     1     2
```